# error of running a stored proceudre in IBM netezza SQL database

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, netezza

I need to create a stored procedure in IBM netezza  SQL database from IBM Aginity workbench.

This is my SQL code to create the SP:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_drop_a_table_if_exists"(varchar(128))
RETURNS boolean
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
declare
    oname alias for $1;
    o record;
begin
    select otype into o
from (
     select 'TABLE' otype from _v_table where tablename = upper(oname)
    union all
    select 'VIEW' otype from _v_view where viewname = upper(oname)
 ) x;

 if found then
    execute immediate 'DROP '||o.otype||' '||oname;
 end if;
end;
END_PROC;
```

I created successfully.

But, when I ran it,

```
   CALL SP_drop_a_table_if_exists('test_a_table':: varchar(128))
```

I got error:

```
 ERROR[42S02] error: function 'sp_drop_a_table_if_exists(varchar)' does not exists
 unable to identify a function that satisdy the given argument types
 you may need to add explicit typecasts
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your stored procedure with mixed case inside of double quotes...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_drop_a_table_if_exists"(varchar(128))
```

...but when you call the stored procedure you don't use double quotes, so the name is being converted all upper case.

```
CALL SP_drop_a_table_if_exists('test_a_table':: varchar(128))
```

Try this instead:

CALL "SP_drop_a_table_if_exists"('test_a_table':: varchar(128))

I should also mention that more recent versions of NPS support this syntax for the DROP TABLE command:

```
DROP TABLE TABLENAME IF EXISTS;
```